# How to add arrow after/before content to Bootstrap button group with active class

Tags: css

I am working on the below demo code. Why am I not able to add arrow content to the `active` btn in Bootstrap button group?

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");


.btn-group .btn.active, .btn:active::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid #333;
  border-right: 10px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">One</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Two</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Three</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean you want it to persist when focused on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want the change to persist, when the button is selected. Currently, it is working when the button has the `:active` pseudo-class (when the button is being *pressed*) — this works fine. However, it will not stay when the mouse click goes up, which would require the `:focus` pseudo-class.

This would require that you add the selector `.btn:focus`, like so:

```
.btn:focus::after
```

---

See the below snippet for a working example.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");


.btn-group .btn:focus::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid #333;
  border-right: 10px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">One</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Two</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Three</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Lambada Ninja, but I am having positioning issue now! I updated the code as you said like ` content: "";  position: absolute;
  border-top: 10px solid #333;  border-left: 10px solid Transparent;  border-right: 10px solid Transparent;` but this force the arrow to right end of the button

Comment: @user1760110 I didn't write that code: I just modified your snippet; you can mess around with the positioning. I'll edit my question soon with a suggestion.

Comment: @user1760110 If you want me to suggest changes to the styling of the arrow, please provide more detail. Where do you want it, and how should it look? If it is a major difference, feel free to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it.